# Python: how to remove single quote on first and last element of list

Tags: python

i have a list that goes like this ['1,2'] and i need to turn it into [1, 2]. Using `int()` won't work. Is there a way to add a single quote and then use `int()`, a way to remove a single quote or is there just a better way to do this?

here is the code that i am using

```
a_list = genres_selected.split()

map_object = map(int, a_list)

genres_selected_use = list(map_object)
```

genres_selected will always be different as it is being passed through ajax form

but here it is "1, 2"

Comment: can you share what's in `genres_selected` ?

Comment: You only have one element, '1, 2', in the list?

Comment: `['1,2']` looks like a list containing one string. `"[1, 2]"` looks like a string. Which one is `genres_selected`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking to remove the string and convert it into an integer. Since the list has a string, you want to split the string using comma delimiter.

```
list_vals = ['1,2,3,4,5,6']
map_object = map(int, list_vals[0].split(','))
print (list(map_object))
```

The output of this will be:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

However, if your list has multiple strings of integers in single quotes, you can do:

```
my_list = ['1,2','3,4','5,6']
num_list = [[int(i) for i in num.split(',')] for num in my_list]
print (num_list)
```

The output of this will be:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
lst = ['1,2', '3,4,5']
new_list = []
for item in lst:
    new_list.extend([int(num) for num in item.strip().split(',')])

print(new_list)
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

One Liner Version

```py
lst = ['1,2', '3,4,5']
print([int(item) for sublist in map(lambda item: item.split(','), lst) for item in sublist])
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```